Raspberry Pi OS transfer from 5 to 3+
I have been working on a project that requires my PI to be outside. Currently it is on a Pi 5. I am not to keep on leaving my 80+ dollar pi outside 24 to collect data. However I do have a couple of rpi 3's just sitting around so I was curious if I can take my current pi 5 install and move it to one of my older ones and what might be the best way to do this.

Just copy the SD Card and it should work, assuming you are using Raspberry Pi OS (unless you have installed some incompatible software).
I use the same Bookworm image on a Pi3+, Pi4 & Pi5 (setting unique hostnames) and all the included software works.
Not all of my user programs (particularly those that use GPIO) work due to the differences in hardware but most that run on Pi5 also work  on other Pi.
